# Bootstrap 3.1 - tooltip is showing just at the bottom position

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a bit of a trouble with bootstrap tooltip. It is showing only on bottom.
HTML code:

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 portfolio-similar">
     <h3>Similar Products</h3>
     <a href="#"><img class="about-me-portfolio" src="images/about/01.jpg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Product 1"></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="about-me-portfolio" src="images/about/02.jpg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Product 2"></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="about-me-portfolio" src="images/about/03.jpg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Product 3"></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="about-me-portfolio" src="images/about/04.jpg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Product 4"></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="about-me-portfolio" src="images/about/05.jpg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Product 5"></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="about-me-portfolio" src="images/about/06.jpg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Product 6"></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="about-me-portfolio" src="images/about/07.jpg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Product 7"></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="about-me-portfolio" src="images/about/08.jpg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Product 8"></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="about-me-portfolio" src="images/about/03.jpg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Product 9"></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="about-me-portfolio" src="images/about/05.jpg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Product 10"></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
```

I tried adding placement as option, but nothing is being changed. I also tried deleting data-placement, but without results. What kind of black sorcery is this?

Comment: Is your HTML well formed? Sometimes having an unclosed element can cause your UI to display incorrectly.

Comment: Double checked it, everything is in place.

Comment: Run your HTML through http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input and see if any errors come back. One thing I see is that your `<img>` tags aren't properly closed. They need to be in the format `<img src='src' alt='image' />`.

Comment: Everything is in order. There is no need to close img tag (since HTML 5).

Comment: I didn't know that about HTML 5. I created a jsFiddle with a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbC76/

Comment: I guess that something is wrong at some other place. Time to check every line of code :D

Comment: Looks like you have another issue going on. Your code works perfect so I would check your code including any js errors.